# How to monkeypatch dunder methods to existing instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, monkeypatching, dynamic-typing

Context:
I'd like to use heapq (and anything else) on objects I didn't create, which don't themselves have a `__lt__` operator. Can I? (without a wrapper class).

the class:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
```

Now, at runtime in the interpreter, I am handed some collection of objects. I want to iterate over them, adding a dunder method (in my case **lt**), eg:

```
n = Node(4)
m = Node(5)

def myLT(self, other):
    return self.val < other.val
```

What I tried:

```
n.__lt__ = types.MethodType(myLT, n)
m.__lt__ = types.MethodType(myLT, m)
```

also

```
n.__lt__ = types.MethodType(myLT, n)
m.__lt__ = types.MethodType(myLT, n)
```

(on the off chance that binding the same functor-thing would improve matters)

```
>>> n < m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Node' and 'Node'
```

even though:

```
>>> n.__lt__(m)
True
```

---

I can use a wrapper class, which is yucky in some ways (extra memory and traversal code gets uglier, but at least leaves the original objects untouched):

```
class NodeWrapper:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.node = n
    def __lt__(self):
        return self.node.val
```

I'm just interested to know if I'm doing something wrong in adding the dunder method, or if this just doesn't work in python 3.x.  I'm using 3.6.9 if that matters.

Comment: A wrapper is probably what you want, honestly. If you want to decrease the memory requirements, use `__slots__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try monkeypatching the dunder by changing the `__class__` property of the instance. As explained in by docs section [Special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup):

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only
> guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in
> the object’s instance dictionary.

---

```
def patch_call(instance, func, memo={}):
    if type(instance) not in memo:
        class _(type(instance)):
            def __lt__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
               return func(self, *arg, **kwargs)
        memo[type(instance)] = _

    instance.__class__ = memo[type(instance)]

patch_call(m, myLT)
patch_call(n, myLT)

n < m
# True
```

[Modified from reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38541437/4909087)

Thanks to @juanpa.arrivilaga for recommending the classes be cached to improve performance.

Comment: You must be doing something different, or I misunderstood.  I tried the above and get: 
`TypeError: myLT() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'`
on onlinegdb

Comment: @wheelreinventor It was a copy paste error in my code, will you take another shot at this now?

Comment: I would cache based on `type(instance)`, or else you are creating a class for each instance. Which can be incredibly wasteful

Comment: fwiw, I observed this experimentally, monkeypatching using this method is about twice as slow, and ~25% more memory given the parameters vs a wrapper class.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga interesting, that seems to address the performance issue OP just mentioned. How would the result be cached? Using `functools.lru_cache`?

Comment: welll you would need to pass the type as the argument if you wanted to use `lru_cache` but you can just keep a dict, something like `seen_types` then `if type(instance) in seen_types: _ = seen_types[type(instance)] else: ...`

Comment: Great comments folks, thank you! @wheelreinventor I invite you to take a look at the revised answer based on juanpa's comment on caching the class.

Comment: finally a real life use case for the mutable default argument!

Comment: Looked promising, but alas, `type(instance)` is final

Comment: This breaks if you want to use a different function with the same class later. (Also, it might be a good idea to say something about unpatching.)