# Monkey-patching `__reduce__` to customize pickling of a single object

Tags: python, pytorch, pickle, monkeypatching

In Python, it's usually easy to monkey-patch a method of an object:

```py
import types

class MyClass:
    def foo(self):
        print("hi")

obj = MyClass()
obj.foo()  # => hi

def myfoo(self):
    print("hello")

obj.foo = types.MethodType(myfoo, obj)
obj.foo()  # => hello
```

This behavior is [not so simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38541015/how-to-monkey-patch-a-call-method) for magic (`__*__`) methods, and I assume something similar to the linked question is happening when this fails:

```py
import pickle, io

class MyClass:
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (MyClass, tuple())

buffer = io.BytesIO()
pickler = pickle.Pickler(buffer)

obj = MyClass()
pickler.dump(obj)

def myreduce(self):
    print("hello")
    return (MyClass, tuple())

obj.__reduce__ = types.MethodType(myreduce, obj)
pickler.dump(obj)
```

Where the above does not output `hello`.

Bizarely, the above *does* output `hello` if you change `pickler.dump` to `pickle.dumps`. Unfortunately, this is not actually a solution for me: I'm trying to customize the serialization of an object in PyTorch, whose `torch.save` uses a `Pickler` object.

Is it possible customize the pickling behavior of a single object?